# How can I fix the error saying DeferFlushOpWorker: Timed out waiting for ops to flush? Android

Tags: android, debugging, serialization, bitmap, deserialization

Running my android application, I get the error mentioned above and then the phone I'm debugging on becomes unresponsive until I force restart it.  The code that's causing the error to occur is in this class:

```
public class BitmapSerializable implements Serializable 
{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6855267020377781806L;

private transient Bitmap image;
private byte[] imageByteArray;

public BitmapSerializable()
{

}

public BitmapSerializable(Bitmap bmp)
{
    setImage(bmp);
}

public Bitmap getImage() {
    if (imageByteArray == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByteArray, 0, imageByteArray.length);
    return image;
}

public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
    this.image = image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    imageByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
}

 }
```

The error is thrown when I serialize this object, read it back in, and then call the getImage() method.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you need a serializable bitmap? given the fact that bitmap is already implement parcelable.

Comment: from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html :
Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport. As such, it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent storage: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data in the Parcel can render older data unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  The problem was not with the serialization itself, the error was occurring when I tried to add the do 
    intent.putExtra("bs", BitmapSerializable);
For anyone else with this error, an attempt to parcelize something similar to my class is probably the cause.